# Автоматическое изменение конкретных данных в mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel, события, scheduler

Разместил проект на **Laravel** на виртуальном хостинге, и возникла необходимость использовать event scheduler в базе данных. В таблице есть записи, в каждой из которых есть дата, устанавливаемая пользователем (дата начала, дата окончания), и статус. Суть такая, что я хотел создать событие в базе данных, которое бы обновляло статус с "Идет сейчас" на "Завершен", в том случае если текущая дата и время больше указанного в "дата окончания". Проблема в том, что на виртуальном хостинге моего хостинг провайдера нельзя включить event scheduler, вместо этого они предлагают перейти на vds где это возможно. Для начала я хотел бы узнать у вас, возможно ли реализовать данную функцию без перехода на vds? Если знаете как сделать это через крон, объясните пожалуйста подробнее - кроном еще не пользовался. Заранее всем спасибо за ответы!

Comment: То, что рассказывают про CRON в вики (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) - вполне достаточно и для знакомства, и для использования в простых случаях (твой - из их числа). А запускать через него надо клиент комстроки mysql (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql.html), передавая ему (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html) необходимые данные для подключения (логин, пароль, имя БД) и текст запроса для выполнения.

Comment: Решим проблему через крон. Просто написал php скрипт с обработкой, и скормил ему.